# Crash on volume button press AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

My app crashes when I tap either volume button. In my view controller, I am calling `setActive` on `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()` and when the user taps a button I play a song with `AVAudioPlayer`. In this view controller, whenever a volume button is pressed, wether the player is playing or not, the app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. I have seen an error message in the debugger occasionally complaining about key-value observing for `outputVolume`.

Any ideas why my app is crashing?

A CLUE: There are two ways I can get to the view controller that is causing the crash. One way causes the crash and the other does not. Either way I am pushing the view controller on to the navigation controller in the same way.

Comment: upload code related to `outputVolume`

Comment: I am not every touching the `outputVolume` property directly. When I push one of the device volume buttons this happens: 

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '{(
    UIButton:0x1b8bf970.minY{id: 743}
)}: An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.
Key path: outputVolume
Observed object: <AVAudioSession: 0x1b97bf00>
Change: {
    kind = 1;
    new = "0.375";
}
Context: 0x0'

Answer (score 2):

Have you added something similar? :

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    audioSession.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "outputVolume",
                             options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
```

if you did, then you need to override this method and do whatever you need in it :

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "outputVolume"{

    }
}
```

Comment: For the AVAudioSession I am only calling `setCategory` and `setActive`, I am not adding any observers or doing anything else other than storing it in a variable of my view controller.

Comment: what are the two ways that lets you get to the viewcontroller ?

Comment: from 2 different view controllers I push the problematic vc on to the current navigation controller

Comment: The error you are receiving says that there is an observer on the outputVolume .. so check back maybe you copy pasted it from somewhere else without noticing

Comment: @InnisBrendan Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the same thing in my app.